# Android crash opening a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, togglebutton

A user told me that he can't open a fragment in my application because he get a crash. I have the logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.dd.androreboot.devicecontrolfragment.onCreateView(devicecontrolfragment.java:162)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

at line 162 i have this code:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        datatoggle = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.datatoggle); 
        datatoggle.setChecked(mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()); //line 162
```

This part of code needs to check if the 3g is connected and if it is, the toggle button state become true. It works in in every device i tryied but not in this one: Galaxy Note 10.1 (p4notewifi). Any helps?

Comment: can you post whole onCreateView method?

Comment: Isn't `mobile` null? If there is no 3G, that instance may be null. Or `dataToggle` may not be properly initialized.

Comment: Can you show some more code of your fragment class ?

Comment: Are you storing your connectivity value in sharedpreference ?

Comment: @GrIsHu here i only check if there is connectivity or not.. Anyway i solved.  :)

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mobile = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    datatoggle = (ToggleButton)v.findViewById(R.id.datatoggle); 


   if(mobile != null) {
    datatoggle.setChecked(mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()); //line 162
   } else {
      datatoggle.setChecked(false); //line 162
   }
```

Comment: Aaaaaaaah so in this way if a device hasn't got the 3g module doesn't crash right? I had not considered that a device does not have the 3g!!

Comment: a NetworkInfo object for the current default network or null if no network default network is currently active.

Answer (score 4):

`getNetworkInfo()` can return `null`. Check for non-null before calling a method on it.

[Specifically](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkInfo%28int%29),

> **Returns**
>
> a `NetworkInfo` object for the requested network type or `null` if the type is not supported by the device.